# excel vba start date range on new record

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I'm after a day of the week starting from "Start Date"(Cell D1) and ending on "End Date" (Cell F1) to auto generate into Cells F3 until last filled in record (A3 to ..)but when the range in column A changes I want the dates to start again
I'm explaining this really bad so see below if that helps

You can see for Dan the start date is 28/04/2023 and runs until the 04/05/2023 but Sam only has 3 records so starts with 28/04/2023 but only to 30/04/2023 then Mike starts at 28/04/2023 and ends on the 04/05/2023

```
        Start Date  28/04/2023  End Date  04/05/2023
No  Name    Location    Rate    Grade   Date
200 Dan                     28/04/2023
200 Dan                     29/04/2023
200 Dan                     30/04/2023
200 Dan                     01/05/2023
200 Dan                     02/05/2023
200 Dan                     03/05/2023
200 Dan                     04/05/2023
300     Sam                                     28/04/2023
300     Sam                                     29/04/2023
300     Sam                                     30/04/2023
500 Mike                        28/04/2023
500 Mike                        29/04/2023
500 Mike                        30/04/2023
500 Mike                        01/05/2023
500 Mike                        02/05/2023
500 Mike                        03/05/2023
500 Mike                        04/05/2023
```

Is this doable at the moment I have the following code but it only generates the days from start to end and doesn't start again with a new record

```
Sub IncreaseDate()

Dim FirstDate As Date
Dim myDate As Date
Dim row As Long

FirstDate = Range("D1").Value - 1

NextDate = Range("F1").Value

row = 3

Do Until FirstDate = NextDate
    FirstDate = FirstDate + 1
    Range("F" & row).Value = FirstDate
    Range("G" & row).Value = "=F" & row
    row = row + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: In your until Loop, check if the previous Name and current name are different, if they are, stop the loop `Do Until FirstDate = NextDate Or [prevNameCell].Value <> [currNameCell].Value `

Comment: You can use a simple formula: `=IF(A3=A2,F2+1,$D$1)`

Comment: Thomas, Never thought of something as simple also Julian thanks for the addition

Comment: they both work thanks for the help